# Why does it skip in the line address?

Tags: c++, sequence

Can someone help me with this? Every time I run the code, it does not display the whole information that is needed. It always has an error at the last information that I type.

I think the error is here:

```
cout << "Address:";
cin.getline(e.address, 50);
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;
     
struct Employee {
    char name[50];
    int salary;
    int employmentStatus;
    char Gender[6];
    int Age;
    char address[50];
};
    
int main() {
    
    Employee e;
         
    cout << "Full Name: " ;
    cin.getline(e.name, 50);
    
    cout << "Age : ";
    cin >> e.Age;
    
    cout << "Gender : ";
    cin >> e.Gender;
    
    cout << "Address: ";
    cin.getline(e.address, 50);
    
    cout << "Salary: ";
    cin >> e.salary;
    
    cout << "Employment Status: ";
    cin >> e.employmentStatus;
    
    // Printing employee details 
    
    cout << "\n*** Employee Details ***" << endl;
    cout << "Name : " << e.name << endl << "Salary : " << e.salary << endl << "Age:" << e.Age << endl << "Gender:" << e.Gender << endl;
    cout << "Employment Status: " << e.employmentStatus << endl << "Address : " << e.address;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: I cannot enter the address and the employment status is diaplaying 'f' only if i enter 'fulltime' in the line employees information

Comment: What's your hope with the two lines `cout << "\n*** Employee Details`
and `***" << endl;` ?

Comment: Does [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) answer your question? (`std::getline` is not the same as `std::cin.getline()` but the issue here is the same)

Comment: Enter pressed after `Gender`  is considered as input and hence address might not be taken properly. 
[DEMO](https://www.godbolt.org/z/8d6n18q8Y)

Comment: After i enter all the informations, it should be displaying the whole infos but it only displays the name, age, gender and salary. It did not display the address and employment status always displaying 0 or blank only

Comment: A demo program that has a link in the above comment solves the problem,  it skips the `enter-key` before adress

Comment: Why the employment status displaying 0?. Im sorry i have so many questions because i am a beginner and i am trying to study on my own

Comment: Please go through [this](https://www.godbolt.org/z/8d6n18q8Y) . Employee status is an integer and it is showing valid out put for it.

Comment: i figured it out already. thank you so much for helping. this subj giving me always a hard time to finish my laboratories. this is my first time to use stack overflow.